# writing array of structures to bin file

Tags: c, arrays, structure, fread, bin

Hello I have an array of structures that I am trying to write to a bin file. However I can only get the 'name' data to show. correctly.the rest comes out as illegible garbage .

```
 struct employee
    {
       char name[15];
        float sal, rate, raise, newsal;
    }e;
```

> Here is my savebin function to save to the bin file.

```
void savebin(struct employee e[], int n)
    {
        FILE *f;
       f=fopen("c:\\cfiles\\employee2.text", "wb");
        fwrite(&e, sizeof(struct employee),n,f);
        fclose(f);
    }
```

Comment: `&e` => `e`, otherwise you're writing the *pointer* only.

Comment: This code seems fine. What output do you expect to get?

Comment: @JacobH of course it is not fine. It is full of undefined behaviour, unless `sizeof` pointer happens to be greater and or equal to `sizeof(struct employee)`.

Comment: Its not printing the rest of the structure values. It only prints name and the rest is gibberish .

Comment: @user2998459 also, you're writing a *binary* file, the rest of it is supposed to be gibberish. But in addition to that your `savebin` doesn't even store the data correctly. Notice that `struct employee e[]` does not declare an array but a pointer, i.e. `struct employee *e`. If you want a better answer you need to provide a proper [mcve]. And please indent your code properly.